# Why can't I import a class into my java file in my Eclipse Maven Project?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, import

I found the following at the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.xd/spring-xd-dirt/1.0.4.RELEASE):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.xd/spring-xd-dirt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-xd-dirt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The homepage given by Maven Repository leads me to [this java file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/ec106725c51d245109b2e5055d9f65e43228ecc1/spring-xd-ui/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/web/controller/support/AuthenticationRequest.java).

Here it is:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.xd.dirt.web.controller.support;

/**
 *
 * @author Gunnar Hillert
 *
 */
public class AuthenticationRequest {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public AuthenticationRequest() {
    }

    public AuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthenticationRequest [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }


}
```

That page tells me that AuthenticationRequest can be imported with

```
import org.springframework.xd.dirt.web.controller.support.AuthenticationRequest;
```

I get an error in pom.xml saying that an artifact is missing. I suppose that library is dependent on another library. I put the artifact in the pom.xml and that error is resolved.

But I still get an error where my import statement is, saying:

> The import org.springframework.xd.dirt.web.controller.support cannot be 
>    resolved

What am I missing? How do I import class AuthenticationRequest?

Comment: You're looking at the **current** source code in the Maven repository, not at the source code of version 1.0.4, that you're using, but which was released in 2015, more than 4 years ago. It seems you're randomly trying to use all the projects which happen to have a class named AuthenticationRequest. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to duplicate this tutorial: https://gorillalogic.com/blog/java-integration-with-amazon-cognito/?unapproved=1278&moderation-hash=8e5cc477bbab499b89fc235fb5a9dd53#comment-1278. She doesn't include information on what to put in the pom.xml file or any import statements. I am trying to piece together the missing information as well as I can. I'm really new at this.

Comment: She does. The article is about AWS Cognito, which is thus part of the AWS SQK. And the section "Let's code" starts by showing the Maven dependencies to add to the project.

Comment: @JBNizet I just created a totally new Maven Project and I included the artifacts that she designated. The SpringSecurityUser and the AuthenticationRequest classes can't be imported using just the dependencies she gave. I have figured out how to import the SpringSecurityUser class. The error in this post occurs again here. I tried putting in the current version, but I get an error message "Missing artifact org.springframework.xd:spring-xd-dirt:jar:
 1.3.1.RELEASE". It looks like I need to find the repository where that missing artifact can be acquired by Maven.

Comment: @JBNizet How do I figure out what to put in the pom.xml file to tell Maven where to find the repository? Would that repository on GitHub be the url? What would the id be?

Comment: Again, you shouldn't use spring-xd-dirt. Use the dependencies that are listed in the article.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I did. I used all the dependencies listed in the article, but I'm not able to import the AuthenticationRequest class. I get the same error as the error this post is about.

Comment: @JBNizet It looks like I've figured out what to include in Maven to designate the repository. I did a search on the internet.

Comment: The use another tutorial about this cognito product of AWS. The AWS documentation should cover how to use its own product. use that.

Comment: @JBNizet That's a good idea. I recall doing a Google search for documentation on how to use Cognito with Java. I don't think I found anything from AWS. I'll do another search. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. I had found that. I haven't found anything in that documentation that shows how to code to use Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching and figured out I need to include the following in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.xd</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xd-dirt</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version> -->
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: The repository part is simply not necessary. Apart from that you should consider to move away from spring-xd cause see the information here: https://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/

Comment: @khmarbaise I got an error when I didn't use the repository tags.

Comment: Of course you get an error cause the version you have mentioned is not on Maven Central ....

Comment: @khmarbaise Right. It's in that repository that I put the tags in for. Doesn't what you say mean I need to put the information for repository in my pom.xml?

Comment: My experience is: If it's not Maven Central you shouldn't use it...or you are testing special things with dev versions etc...

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven Central has an older version that doesn't work with the code I'm duplicating in a tutorial. I decided to use the newer version from spring-repo so that I wouldn't have to change the code that was given me in the tutorial.